# How to drop columns with empty headers in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a DF:

```
Name1 Name2 NUll Name3 NULL Name4
abc   abc        null       abc
abc   abc        null       abc
abc   abc        null       abc
abc   abc        null       abc
```

Can I use dropna, to keep Name3 as a column with all empty values? Yet still drop both Null columns. 
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that the column label is `None` or a string value equal to `'NULL'`?

Comment: That the label is null. It is just a totally empty column in the xls file.

Comment: you have `NULL` and `NUll` so those kind of look like strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)?

```
In [3]: df = pd.read_clipboard()
Out[3]: 
  Name1 Name2  NUll Name3  NULL  Name4
0   abc   abc        null          abc
1   abc   abc        null          abc
2   abc   abc        null          abc
3   abc   abc        null          abc

In [4]: df.drop(["NUll", "NULL"], axis=1)
Out[4]: 
  Name1 Name2 Name3  Name4
0   abc   abc  null    abc
1   abc   abc  null    abc
2   abc   abc  null    abc
3   abc   abc  null    abc
```

Answer (score 1):

I was importing some data from a google sheet which had empty column names, this did the required for me:

```
    # drop those with empty column names
    self.df.drop([""], axis=1, inplace=True)
```